# Using Newtonsoft Jschema, how can I validate derived class properties based on an abstract class?

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-core, json.net, jsonschema

An example would be I have an array of the abstract class `Production` which has derived classes of `Movie` and `Series`. I have an array in the schema that is a `Production[]` which can hold either a `Movie` or `Series`. I'm validating schema that is being provided to us by a third party. I am only validating, not deserializing so I am validating it with the validation stream.

When I validate that array, it only validates against the properties within `Production`. It skips any properties that are within the derived classes. How can I get it to validate against the correct derived class properties? I have a `ProductionType` property on `Production` which is a one to one match to the derived class.

I have tried adding the derived class schemas to the "AdditionalItems" in the `ProductionGenerationProvider` and manually validate against it in the `ProductionValidationProvider`. Did this by `value.Validate(matchedSchemaItem)`. This causes a whole new validation to be spawned off instead of validate it within the context of the current validation.

I also tried using the `OneOf` property on the schema by passing in the references to all the derived types but it just tells me that it didn't validate against any of the items in OneOf.

Is there a way another way to do this? I assume this is a solved issue and I just haven't come across the solution.

Comment: 1) How are you implementing polymorphism?  Via a `"$type"` `TypeNameHandling` property?  Or via some custom discriminator property on `Production`?  2) *I have tried adding the derived class schemas to the "AdditionalItems" in the ProductionGenerationProvider and manually validate against it in the ProductionValidationProvider* - might you please [edit] your question to share what you tried, that did not work?

Comment: @dbc I'm only using this to validate a schema. So will I need to make sure that there is a `$type` on the JSON that I'm being provided with? If that is there, will the validator know which reference in the schema to check against? Does it matter that I am validating it as a stream?